# Only first value from String / Array taken when given as paramenter

Tags: powershell, outlook

I create an arraylist with all users from the AD in it.

```
$array = [System.Collections.ArrayList]::New()

Get-AzureADUser -All $true | ForEach-Object -Process {
    if ($_.mail) {
        $array.Add($_.mail)
    }
}
```

Afterwards I convert the array to a string separated by comma

```
$array = $($array -join ",")
```

Now, if I use the array in another cmdlet (Outlook inbox rule), only the very first value gets taken.

```
New-InboxRule -Name "New Rule" -Mailbox "John Doe" -MoveToFolder ":\Inbox" -SentTo $array
```

In Outlook I only see one single user.

`$array` has the correct value and format

```
Email,Email,Email,...
```

and when I copy/paste the output of `Write-Host $array` manually as a parameter, it works fine.

Comment: It's not an array.  It's a single string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in Ansgar Wiecher's [helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57075944/9902555), you should pass an array, not comma-separated list to `-SentTo` parameter.

However, while testing this I checked with `Get-InboxRule` that this property is being populated by distinguished names of mailboxes. If I specified email address, it gave me errors all the time (regardless the format).

The property you want to use can be easily extracted to array using `.propertyName`:

```bsh
$array = (Get-Mailbox -ResultSize Unlimited).distinguishedname
New-InboxRule -Name "New Rule" -Mailbox $name -MoveToFolder ":\Inbox" -SentTo $array
```

---

**NOTE**: I'm not sure what's the purpose of creating such rule, but if you want to bypass 'Junk', I'd strongly suggest to use [`New-TransportRule` cmdlet](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/exchange/policy-and-compliance/new-transportrule?view=exchange-ps) instead of creating separate inbox rules on user level.

Setting SCL to -1 based on some conditions (sender address is not necessarily the best as it can be spoofed easily) should do the job.

Comment: Thanks, I am creating an email archive and need rules to manage the email flow.

Comment: @LouisJ.you're welcome. Please remember to accept either mine or Ansgar's answer if they are working for you.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/exchange/mailboxes/new-inboxrule) the parameter `-SentTo` expects an array, not a comma-separated string.

Change your code to something like this:

```
$array = Get-AzureADUser -All $true | Where-Object { $_.mail }
New-InboxRule ... -SentTo $array
```